# Getting all python-rom objects into a list

Tags: python, flask, redis

I am working with flask and redis. I've decided to try the rom redis orm (http://pythonhosted.org/rom/) to manage some mildly complex data structures. I have a list of objects, lets say:

```
urls = ['www.google.com', 'www.example.com', 'www.python.org']
```

I also have the rom model:

```
class Stored_url(rom.Model):
    url = rom.String(required=True, unique=True, suffix=True)
    salt = rom.String()
    hash = rom.String()
    created_at = rom.Float(default=time.time)
```

This appears to be working on my dev setup.  I have loaded about 25 'Stored_url' objects into REDIS (confirmed at cmd line). I am trying to come up with a way of getting all the objects of type Stored_url into a python list.

```
>>> test = Mymodels.Stored_url
>>> type(test)
Out[35]: rom._ModelMetaclass
>>> h =test.query.filter(url ='.').all()
>>> h.count()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\envs\virtalenvs\flaskenv\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3035, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-37-43f0dc233d70>", line 1, in <module>
    h.count()
TypeError: count() takes exactly one argument (0 given)
```

I thought h would have  a list of objects. What am I doing wrong? (I was filtering by "." because i figured on urls would have it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems with the code you have provided which explain why you get the results that you get.

The first problem is that your query `test.query.filter(url ='.').all()` will return an empty list. This will return an empty list simply because you don't have a valid index to be used with the filter you have specified. You do have 2 indexes for that column - a unique index (useful for looking up urls by exact string) and a suffix index (useful for finding urls that end with a certain string) - but neither offer the ability to filter by what would be in the relational world a 'like' query. A prefix index (created with `prefix=True`) would let you use `test.query.like(url='*.')`, but that would be very slow (it does an index scan instead of direct lookup[1]).

To help prevent index/query-related issues like this, I have added QueryError exceptions when users attempt to filter their data by indexes that don't exist. I'll be releasing 0.31.4 a bit later tonight with those changes.

The second error you have, which is the cause of the exception, is that you call `.count()` without an argument. At the point of your `h.count()` call, `type(h) == list`, and Python list objects require an argument to count values equal to the provided argument in the list. If you skipped the `.all()` portion of your original query, you would get a query object back. That query object has a `.count()` method, and would return a count of matched results.

[1] Not all 'like' queries in rom are slow, but those that are fast require non-wildcard prefixes to limit data ranges to scan/filter.

Comment: Thanks very much Josiah.